# DPFields display values in module

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field, fields

I've been using the Joomla extension DP fields to add fields to the joomla content model.  The extension is great, I started using it after watching Macro Dings' talk at Joomla Day UK 2016 on YouTube.

So it is working really well for views in com_content, in terms of showing field values in article and blog views.  However, I'm struggling to figure out how to display the data in a module or template override of a module.

For example, I'd like to show a couple of field values in a template override of the "mod_articles_category" module.

I was hoping there would be a helper and an class/api call to use from there, but I've not found one yet.

About DP Fields...
https://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpfields

Marco Dings' Joomla Day UK 2016 talk on DP fields...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDh1IPuZAVA

DP Fields dev docs...
https://joomla.digital-peak.com/documentation/162-dpfields/2756-developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you like it. If you just need the value, then use the field model as you can see here https://github.com/Digital-Peak/DPFields/blob/master/com_dpfields/admin/helpers/dpfields.php#L137. Keep in mind that the value is then not prepared. If the onContentPrepare event is fired on the article, then the fields are already attached to the item(article).

Comment: Any chance one of you could post an example of the finished product? I can't seem to get this to do anything in a warp7 override.